# SegmentTimeline in MP4Box

Tags: mpeg-dash, dash.js, mp4box

Based on DASH standard, there are 4 DASH segment referencing schemes. SegmentBase, SegmentList, SegmentTemplate and SegmentTimline.

How to create a MPD file with SegmentTimeline scheme in MP4Box?

In SegmentTimeline, there is `r` attribute which is repetition of segment, how to generate it in MP4Box?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This blog post by Romaine from gpac has some useful info:  http://www.gpac-licensing.com/2014/08/21/ibc-2014-dash-avc264-support-in-gpac/

Cheers

Will

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `-segment-timeline` option on top of your DASH options.